# SWRevealViewController not passing parent in XCode 7

Tags: ios, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer, swrevealviewcontroller

There's a similar thread on the SWRevealViewController github page that isn't going anywhere fast, so I thought I'd put this up for the experts here.

I have SWRevealViewController 2.4 at use in my app.  It's been working fine for months (was previously using 2.3).  I noticed on our our beta testers had iOS 9 Beta on his iPad and the reveals weren't working; but it wasn't a high priority so we moved on.

Today I updated to XCode 7, still testing against iOS 8.4.

In my 1st front view controller everything seems to be working fine.  But as soon as I segue to my next front view controller I loose access to the SWRevealViewController.

This line in the "viewDidLoad" of the next view controller

```
_revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
if ( _revealViewController )
{
    [_sidebarButton setTarget: _revealViewController];
    [_sidebarButton setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
}
```

no longer works because "self.revealViewController" is always nil.

I have also tried passing a global reference to the first revealviewcontroller and although it isn't nil, it doesn't work either.  The sidebarbutton does not work, and I was calling "rightRevealToggleAnimated" which no longer works either.

Again, no code or iOS version changes; just updated to XCode 7.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work reliably by making sure all segues on the storyboard were SWRevealViewControllerPushSegue's, AND also capturing the reference to the revealview controller in my global data class and using the same reference everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed the sidebar problem.

1. override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

}

2. @IBOutlet weak var open: UIBarButtonItem!
3. @IBAction func open(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

   ```
   open.target = self.revealViewController()
   open.action = Selector("revealToggle:")
   ```

   }

Comment: Formatting could be better.